# Python reading from csv file how to remove quotes from integers only

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to run a program reading from a csv file that puts quotes around all values.  I would like it to read without quotes around integers.  Please see below the outputs and code that I'm using now.  Unfortunately, the code removes all quotes as of now.

output:

```
[[Ben, B, 1, 58222], [Vicki, C, 2, 39300]]
```

desired output:

```
[['Ben', 'B', 1, 58222], ['Vicki', 'C', 2, 39300]]
```

```
f=open("IT244_Unit_5_Data.csv", "r")
employeeRecordsFromFile = f.read() 
f.close()

#create nested list of data from employee record file
employeeRecords = [b.split(',') for b in employeeRecordsFromFile.split('\n')] 
translation = {39: None} 
print (str(employeeRecords).translate(translation))
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `csv` module to read the CSV file?

Comment: try using rt instead r only.

Comment: I just tried using rt and removed the bottom two lines of code with no luck. [['Ben', 'B', '1', '58222'], ['Vicki', 'C', '2', '39300']] was the result.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Could you elaborate on using csv module?  I am only 3 weeks into a Python class but would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks!